# remove dynamic part of url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to remove the dynamic part of a url:

```
example.com/pagename/?btag=a_233b_230c_&affid=201
```

so remove everything after and including "?"

But I don't want this rule to apply to this directory:

```
example.com/wp-content/?attr=1345
```

Is it possible to do this with .htaccess?

Thanks, any help is appreciated
Jon

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content

That might help:-d just repeat for other folders.